# Ограничение символов QTextEdit

Tags: c++, qt

Есть ли в Qt метод, который ограничивает кол-во вводимых символов в QTextEdit или придется самому его реализоаывать?

Comment: А почему именно QTextEdit? Можете коротко объяснить для какой задачи нужно это ограничение?

Comment: Нужно, что б пользователь ввел 1-3х значное число.

Comment: Тогда лучше QLineEdit использовать. Либо в QTextEdit перехватывать событие ввода и не давать вводить лишний символ, или перехватывать сигнал textChanged и тоже резать лишние символы. Но это для вашей задачи, я думаю, излишнее

Comment: Спасибо, попробую с ним. :)

Comment: @gil9red Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы рекомендовал использовать [QLineEdit](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html) и ограничивать через [setMaxLength](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#maxLength-prop)

---

Но если таки делать через [QTextEdit](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html) / [QPlainTextEdit](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qplaintextedit.html), тут я вижу два способа:

- Через метод-событие [keyPressEvent](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qplaintextedit.html#keyPressEvent) (у обоих виджетов одинаковый метод). Т.е. ловим ввод и проверяем сколько уже текста есть. Дополнительно придется ловить событие вставки из буфера обмена, например через метол-событие [insertFromMimeData](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qplaintextedit.html#insertFromMimeData) (у обоих виджетов одинаковый метод).
- Через отлов сигнала [textChanged](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qplaintextedit.html#textChanged) (у обоих виджетов одинаковый сигнал). Т.е. ловим сигнал и обрезаем лишний текст